ACF: register subfields for existent parent "group" field depend on other fields post data with PHP
I really need help or advice from experts. My task is to create a set of text fields in the field type=group (which is created in the admin panel) depending on the value of the post fields.
I’m actually making a table editor. The two repeating fields will contain the names of the columns and rows. Now I want to make a grid table with text fields. Calculate their % width (to make a view like a table) and add this unique set of text fields for each page.
But for example, I need to solve the simplest problem – create a subfield for an existing field group. But I want to set subfields in an existing (empty in the admin panel) group personally for each post.
I would be eternally grateful for your help as it will open the door to many things in the future. Thank you!
P.S. I saw how to add a separate group of fields using PHP.  This is worse for me, but I can create a separate group. However, the question remains the same - how to determine a set of fields in a group depending on the values of the fields of this post (so retrieve post ID)?
